# Can a function be a part of $R(\sin x,\cos x)$ if it only contains elements of $\sin x$ or $\cos x$

Tags: notation

My textbook says that integrals of the form $\int R(\sin x,\cos x)$ can be simplified using some substitutions (like $\tan \frac{x}{2}=t $. My question is would those substitutions be applicable if R is just a function of $\sin x$ without any term of $\cos x$ or vice versa? For example if we have to integrate $ \frac {1}{1-\cos^4x}$ in terms of $dx$

Or in a more general case if $R(x,y)$ is a function would $5x$ or $10y^2+2$ be an element of the function?

Comment: $f(x) = 4$ is a function of $x$ yet is independent of x. Similiar logic applies to your question

Comment: Have you heard of constant functions? $f(x) = 0$ is a perfectly valid function of $x$ even if the $x$ doesn't figures in the expression $0$. In the same way, $f(x,y) = 5x$ is a valid function

Comment: @egglog thank you